# Getting the user's information on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an iPhone App using Xcode 4.2 .

is there is a way to gather the user's information (name , phone number ,e-mail  etc...) upon download from the App store ? if yes , how ?

Comment: No, there isn't. For good reason.

Comment: Ask your users to input them if you really need them.

Comment: why all the downvoting, folks? The question is a good & succinct (to-the-point) one, but of course the answer is "no way is that legal".

Comment: There is no need for a down vote. This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't legally gather user's name, phone number, etc.

That would be a privacy violation, and Apple doesn't allow developers to do such things.

Answer (score 2):

NO.. not with official iOS sdk.. Apple will not allow your app in app store if you do so!

Answer (score 2):

You can have the app politely request the user to enter some info about themselves; but according Apple's approval guidelines, can't require that they actually do enter any identifying info.

In addition, Apple provides no identifying info to the developer, and likely can't according to their iTunes privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

That's what iOS is all about - apps running in a sandbox to keep the user safe and only sharing data with **user interaction**. You can only get user data by using the `AddressBook.framework`, which the user has to engage with to allow your app to access that information.

If you're looking for an easy way to get user data, switch to Android. ;)

Comment: There was no need to throw in that last comment about android. Are you trying to create a flamewar?

Comment: I think it is a commonly known fact that there're security problems on Android that allow apps to access almost any data they want. That's all I am pointing out.